# Combining cell_data_sets using monocle3

Tags: r

I am trying to combine 2 cell_data_sets using the monocle3 package in RStudio:

```
combine_cds()
```

However, the NAs and conflicts result in the cells not aligning and separating based on the two datasets. I am mainly confused because I have run this code before, and the cells from the different datasets integrated. However, when I plot the cells now, after combining the cell_data_sets, preprocessing, aligning, reducing the dimension of the new cell_data_set (called "big_cds"), and clustering the cells, the plot shows the cell clusters separated by the two datasets. If you have any suggestions as to why the code isn't integrating the datasets when it did before and/or how to fix this problem, it would be greatly appreciated - thank you in advance!

Code used:

```
big_cds <- combine_cds(list(1_cds,2_cds))

#Find expressed genes
big_cds <- detect_genes(big_cds)
cellCutoff<-10
expressed_genes <- fData(big_cds)$gene_short_name[fData(big_cds)$num_cells_expressed >= cellCutoff]

#Preprocessing
big_cds <- preprocess_cds(big_cds,
                      num_dim = 20,
                      verbose=TRUE,
                      cores=8,
                      use_genes=expressed_genes)
plot_pc_variance_explained(big_cds)

#Align big_cds
big_cds = align_cds(big_cds, num_dim = 100, alignment_group = "dataset")

#Dimension reduction
big_cds <- reduce_dimension(big_cds,
                        max_components=2,
                        preprocess_method='PCA',
                        reduction_method="UMAP",
                        umap.metric="cosine",
                        umap.n_neighbors= 15L,
                        umap.fast_sgd=TRUE,
                        cores=8,
                        verbose=TRUE
                        )

#Clustering
big_cds <- cluster_cells(big_cds,
                     #resolution=NULL,
                    python_home = "C:/Users/myname/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.8.5-h5fd99cc_2_cpython",
                     resolution=c(10^seq(-6,-3)),
                     k=50,
                     verbose=TRUE
                     )

#Plot cells
plot_cells(big_cds)
```